# Get the JavaScript variable in formsubmit

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with screen scraping. In the page the links are available as follows,

```
<a id="linkbuttonAlphaA" href="javascript:__doPostBack('linkbuttonAlphaA','')">A</a>
<a id="linkbuttonAlphaB" href="javascript:__doPostBack('linkbuttonAlphaB','')">B</a>

<a id ="linkbuttonAlphaC"ref="javascript:__doPostBack('linkbuttonAlphaC','')">C</a>
```

The `__doPostBack` function contains this

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
```

In this is it possible to set `eventTarget` and `eventArgument` manually? That means by passing that values in the URL and call the `__doPostBack` function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hard code the values why not use two hidden fields and set their values and post the page. It would not be displayed on the url.

If you look at this link http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=18, it would make things clear to you.